# jQuery File Upload: using counter inside of $.each

Tags: counter, blueimp, jquery-file-upload

I'm using jQuery-File-Upload's fileuploaddone callback to insert hidden inputs to the form to send it to the server:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<input type="hidden" name="file' + index + '" value="' + file.name + '">').appendTo('#fileupload');
    }); 
});
```

The problem is that counter `index` doesn't increment. That what is inserted into my form:

```
<input type="hidden" name="file0" value="filename.png">
<input type="hidden" name="file0" value="filename2.png">
etc
```

I tried to use a separate counter:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
    var i = 0;
    $.each(data.files, function (index, file) {
        $('<input type="hidden" name="file' + i + '" value="' + file.name + '">').appendTo('#fileupload');
        i++;
    }); 
});
```

But result is the same. What is the trick?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collections `data.files` only contain 1 object each, hence why your counters/index never increment.

Take a look at the following line.

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
```

The event 'fileuploaddone' is occurring *for each* file.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But how can I have name="file1", name="file2", etc in my inputs?

Comment: Declare the `i` counter globally.